# Monitor heap space on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit

Is there a plugin for Maven or something like that, that shows me how much heap space I am using while my JUnit tests are running?

My problem is that I have all my tests running on a Jenkins, but I feel like I have heap space problems and I can't find a way to check the heap space on the Jenkins, how much each test is using, what the current free heap space is, etc.

EDIT:

My surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.22.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
         <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
         <argLine>${argLine} -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
         <argLine>${argLine} -Xms1024m</argLine>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You can run each unit test locally and use VisualVM or depending on your IDE the IDE....

Comment: Can you post your pom, especially the surefire plugin configuration. Surefire has a lot of options to fork, thread and configure memory

Comment: What are the symptoms of your problem?